# iPhone OS Memory Warnings. What Do The Different Levels Mean?

Tags: memory-management, ipad, warnings

Regarding the black art of managing memory on iPhone OS devices: what do the different levels of memory warning mean. Level 1? Level 2? Does the dial go to 11?

Context: After an extensive memory stress testing period - including running my iPad app with the iPod music player app playing, I am inclined to ignore the random yet infrequent memory warnings I am receiving. My app **never** crashes. Ever. My app is leak free. And, well, the mems warnings just don't seem to matter.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Basically the warnings mean that the *device* is running low on memory, and that, "If you could please free some memory you aren't actively using that'd be **swell!**". If your memory management is tight, and you have no objects that could practically be discarded, just pass the message along and ignore it.

Comment: LOL "If you could please free some memory you aren't actively using that'd be swell!" Priceless ;-)  

Cheers

Comment: You sound like a grissled veteran of the iPhone OS wack-a-mole memory dance.

Answer (score 195):

Memory level warnings are logged by SpringBoard. As an app developer you don't need to care about it. Just responding to `-{application}didReceiveMemoryWarning` is enough.

---

There are 4 levels of warnings (0 to 3). These are set from the kernel memory watcher, and can be obtained by the [not-so-public function `OSMemoryNotificationCurrentLevel()`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.1.4/include/libkern/OSMemoryNotification.h).

```
typedef enum {
    OSMemoryNotificationLevelAny      = -1,
    OSMemoryNotificationLevelNormal   =  0,
    OSMemoryNotificationLevelWarning  =  1,
    OSMemoryNotificationLevelUrgent   =  2,
    OSMemoryNotificationLevelCritical =  3
} OSMemoryNotificationLevel;
```

How the levels are triggered is not documented. SpringBoard is configured to do the following in each memory level:

1. Warning (not-normal) — Relaunch, or delay auto relaunch of nonessential background apps e.g. Mail.
2. Urgent — Quit all background apps, e.g. Safari and iPod.
3. Critical and beyond — The kernel will take over, probably killing SpringBoard or even reboot.

Killing the active app (jetsam) is not handled by SpringBoard, but `launchd`.

Comment: Thanks for this. It was a toss between you and Williham the comedian on this question. Humor wins. Cheers.

Comment: Hi,
I have same issue. After running the application continuously ffor more than 5 times, I am getting Received memory warning. Level=1 for  20 times, but application is not crashing.
But when I get this message, Received memory warning. Level=2 my application is crashing.

Level2 is appearing after Level1 appearing for nearly 20 times. How can I make my application not to crash.
Thank you

Comment: @Kenny: Less memory means , how much can we use maximum. How much can we have live bytes. In my crash log I got this.

Free pages:        371  
Wired pages:       12192  
Purgeable pages:   0  
Largest process:   DTMobileIS  
What this mean ? Where I should take care ?
Thank You.

Comment: @srik: You'd better [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @kennytm: is this still possible with ios8? I've seen that the function is defined in `libsystem_c.dylib`. It would be great if I could go ahead and use it. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

From [OSMemoryNotification.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.1.4/include/libkern/OSMemoryNotification.h),

```
/*
** Threshold values for notifications
*/

typedef enum {
    OSMemoryNotificationLevelAny      = -1,
    OSMemoryNotificationLevelNormal   =  0,
    OSMemoryNotificationLevelWarning  =  1,
    OSMemoryNotificationLevelUrgent   =  2,
    OSMemoryNotificationLevelCritical =  3
} OSMemoryNotificationLevel;
```

totoal 5 levels of memory warning (-1,3).

Regarding Memory Level warning description, @KennyTM's answer is excellent.

I want to add several related points which may help PM and others.

---

**What should you do when having Memory Level Warning?**

Upon receiving any of these warnings, your handler method should respond by immediately freeing up any unneeded memory. For example, the default behavior of the UIViewController class is to purge its view if that view is not currently visible; subclasses can supplement the default behavior by purging additional data structures. An app that maintains a cache of images might respond by releasing any images that are not currently onscreen.

---

**How to observe Memory Level warning?**

From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html

When the system dispatches a low-memory warning to your app, respond immediately. iOS notifies all running apps whenever the amount of free memory dips below a safe threshold. (It does not notify suspended apps.) If your app receives this warning, it must free up as much memory as possible. The best way to do this is to remove strong references to caches, image objects, and other data objects that can be recreated later.

UIKit provides several ways to receive low-memory warnings, including the following:

- Implement the applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning: method of your app
  delegate.
- Override the didReceiveMemoryWarning method in your custom
  UIViewController subclass.
- Register to receive the
  UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotificationnotification.

---

**How to Reduce Your App’s Memory Footprint?**

- Eliminate memory leaks.
- Make resource files as small as possible.
- Use Core Data or SQLite for large data sets.
- Load resources lazily.
- Build your program using the Thumb option.

Details at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html

---

**How to allocate memory wisely?**

- *Reduce your use of autoreleased objects* : With automatic reference
  counting (ARC), it is better to alloc/init objects and let the
  compiler release them for you at the appropriate time. This is true
  even for temporary objects that in the past you might have
  autoreleased to prevent them from living past the scope of the
  current method.
- *Impose size limits on resources* : Avoid loading a large resource file
  when a smaller one will do. Instead of using a high-resolution image,
  use one that is appropriately sized for iOS-based devices. If you
  must use large resource files, find ways to load only the portion of
  the file that you need at any given time. For example, rather than
  load the entire file into memory, use the mmap and munmap functions
  to map portions of the file into and out of memory. For more
  information about mapping files into memory.
- *Avoid unbounded problem sets* : Unbounded problem sets might require
  an arbitrarily large amount of data to compute. If the set requires
  more memory than is available, your app may be unable to complete the
  calculations. Your apps should avoid such sets whenever possible and
  work on problems with known memory limits.