# how to solve memory warning level 1 in ipad?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented pdf reader application in which i have load one controller in UIScrollvew and implemented pagging functionality.Its working fine.But after 28 pagging show memory warning level 1.I dont know where is the memory leak.Please help me solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way we can resolve this without knowing a lot more about your specific application.  Please provide more details about how you are loading your PDF pages, for example.

Answer (score 1):

A memory warning level 1 don't implies that your application is running out of memory. It's often related to background apps (Mail or Media player, for instance). Anyway, level 1 isn't critical (level 2 & 3 are). Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915247/iphone-os-memory-warnings-what-do-the-different-levels-mean) will help you?

Answer (score 1):

If your app releases memory in response to a memory warning, then it's fine. Memory warnings are pretty normal if you're doing any caching of large objects.

If scrolling some more causes your app to get killed, then you have a problem.

Comment: yes i have add webview in scrollview up to 200 times for implementing paging.But its working fine up to 30 pages after that i have got memory warning level2 then it crash.please advice me for this question.thanks

Comment: Remove the old webviews when they go off-screen.