# "Received memory warning. Level=2" with 4.x?

Tags: ios4

With iOS 4.x I am seeing more and more "Received memory warning. Level=2" when I run stress tests against my app. Anyone else seeing this?

Mainly happens when dismissing a send level view controller. I am not using IB to construct my UIView's

Answer (score 3):

I've never even seen iOS 4.x, but this might help anyway: [iPhone OS Memory Warnings. What Do The Different Levels Mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915247/iphone-os-memory-warnings-what-do-the-different-levels-mean)