# what is a memory warning, how do we respond to it

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone OS Memory Warnings. What Do The Different Levels Mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915247/iphone-os-memory-warnings-what-do-the-different-levels-mean)

what is a memory warning, how do we respond to it

Answer (score 5):

Check this SO question

[iPhone OS Memory Warnings. What Do The Different Levels Mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915247/iphone-os-memory-warnings-what-do-the-different-levels-mean)
Check Kenny's answer

Memory level warnings are logged by SpringBoard. As an app developer you don't need to care about it. Just responding to `-{application}didReceiveMemoryWarning` is enough.

There are 4 levels of warnings (0 to 3). These are set from the kernel memory watcher, and can be obtained by the not-so-public function `OSMemoryNotificationCurrentLevel()`.

```
typedef enum {
    OSMemoryNotificationLevelAny      = -1,
    OSMemoryNotificationLevelNormal   =  0,
    OSMemoryNotificationLevelWarning  =  1,
    OSMemoryNotificationLevelUrgent   =  2,
    OSMemoryNotificationLevelCritical =  3
} OSMemoryNotificationLevel;
```

How the levels are triggered is not documented. SpringBoard is configured to do the following in each memory level:

1. Warning (not-normal) — Relaunch, or delay auto relaunch of nonessential background apps e.g. Mail.
2. Urgent — Quit all background apps, e.g. Safari and iPod.
3. Critical and beyond — The kernel will take over, probably killing SpringBoard or even reboot.

Killing the active app (jetsam) is not handled by SpringBoard, but launchd.

**UPDATE**

Pls go through the Apple Reference documents on [Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) also