# Xcode 4 question about object library and NSLog

Tags: iphone, xcode

Two questions.  All of a sudden, not sure why, maybe I hit the incorrect hot key, but my Object Library for .xibs in IB now shows NS items used in Mac development and not my typical iOS elements.  How do I bring that back?

Second question, if I run an app in the simulator and it says in the console:

```
Received memory warning.Level = 1
```

What should I start with in troubleshooting?  This is on an old 3G iPhone.  Thanks!

Comment: These are two unrelated questions. Split them up into two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding your second question: you should start troubleshooting your app for an excess of memory allocation and, if you can, look for memory leaks

maybe you want to look at this topic: [iPhone OS Memory Warnings. What Do The Different Levels Mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915247/iphone-os-memory-warnings-what-do-the-different-levels-mean)

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: restart XCode.

For the second question: If the warning is infrequent and your app is not crashing, don't worry about it.  Regardless or warnings or not you should be doing memory testing for leaks and also make sure your app responds to didReceiveMemoryWarning notifications.  These warnings are normal and vary greatly depending on what other processes are running.