# Warning Received memory warning. Level=2 iPhone

Tags: iphone

my application crashes showing

```
Received memory warning. Level=2.
```

Complete warning is

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
```

Please help

It is working fine in iphone simulator but not on actually divice

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915247/iphone-os-memory-warnings-what-do-the-different-levels-mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't is just a memory problem ? The "RAM" of iPad and iPhone is really limited, if you use too much of it, the system will send level 1 warning and level 2 warning. If you still use too much memory after that, it will kill your application.

You don't encounter the problem on the simulator because your computer have much more memory.

If you want to simulate such memory warning to see how your code behave in such a situation. Use this code :

```
// Do as if there has been a memory warning in the simulator
+ (void)simulateMemoryWarningInSimulator
{
     #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    #ifdef DEBUG
        CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), (CFStringRef)@"UISimulatedMemoryWarningNotification", NULL, NULL, true);
    #endif
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this Framework in your xcode project - libxml.dylib

Yes and if it looks like a memory issue, run your app on a device coupled with Instruments. It should show you what exactly is causing the memory issues.

Comment: edited response. if it doesn't work, try running instruments to find what is causing the issue.