# Received memory warning in my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone OS Memory Warnings. What Do The Different Levels Mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915247/iphone-os-memory-warnings-what-do-the-different-levels-mean)

I received in my app a lot of `Received memory warning. Level=2` , there is a way to know which object make the memory warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Clean All Targets and delete build folder then go to Run -> Run With Performance Tool -> Leaks..
Using this, Your app will run with instruments.. this will show you where memory leak occurs..

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect your code using Instruments, which is a tool that comes with the SDK. I'd recommend using Allocations and Leaks to see which objects are kept alive for how long and if you have any leaks that cause the warnings.