# How do I log the level for an iOS memory warning?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone OS Memory Warnings. What Do The Different Levels Mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915247/iphone-os-memory-warnings-what-do-the-different-levels-mean)

I can see memory warnings in the console, and write them using `NSLog(@"%s", __ func__)`, but I don't know how to determine the level of the memory warning.

Is there a way to programmatically determine the level of a memory warning that my iOS application is receiving?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is still the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2915477/341994

Comment: Uhm, you mean I have to use that third party framework just to log the level of memory warning?

Comment: @matt - That doesn't express how to determine the memory warning levels, so I think this could be a valid question on its own.

Comment: @BradLarson I guess my thought was that the q. showed lack of research, since the info was easy to find on StackOverflow, and so didn't need a separate entry. But if you have Mighty Power to vote against closing the question, pls go right ahead if I'm mistaken about this. Thx!