# "Received memory warning" message

Tags: ios

I keep receiving memory warning in the debugger windows when I'm running my app through a real device. The application seems all right and the app did not crash, but I just keep receiving warning.

The information looks like this:

```
2014-03-13 13:04:07.265 My App[41521:907] Received memory warning.
2014-03-13 13:04:19.104 My App[41521:907] Received memory warning.
2014-03-13 13:04:35.427 My App[41521:907] Received memory warning.
```

What do these warnings mean?

Comment: It means that iOS thinks you're taking up too much memory and need to free up some stuff.  (I believe in later versions iOS will automatically free up unused view controllers, etc.)  You do need to double-check that you don't have any serious leaks.

Comment: I'm using autoreleasepool where I can check if I have any leak?? Also, my device is 3gs pretty old model.

Comment: You need to use the instruments.

Answer (score 0):

It means you app are likely to use too many memory.  `Received memory warning.` alway means the warning level is 1, it's just a warning, if you don't do some memory release operation or optimize memory using, the memory will grow up then receive the high warning then crash.

[The link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915247/iphone-os-memory-warnings-what-do-the-different-levels-mean) will maybe help you more.